# When Stitching using HotChocolate, How Can A Remote Schema's Type Be Renamed?

Tags: c#, .net, graphql, hotchocolate

Here's my scenario. I have a GraphQL gateway that stitches a dozen or so remote schemas together, using the following code:

```cs
services.AddHttpClient(schema.TypeName, c => c.BaseAddress = new Uri(schema.Url));
```

```cs
public virtual void Add(IRequestExecutorBuilder builder, bool ignoreRootTypes = true)
{
    var type = this.GetType();
    builder.AddRemoteSchema(type.Name, ignoreRootTypes);
}
```

Assume that the remote schemas are immutable. One of the remote schemas has a type called `Name`. This appears to be a reserved keyword, because during stitching, I get the exception:

> For more details look at the `Errors` property.
>
> 1. An item with the same key has already been added. Key: Name

I can correct this error by modifying the `Name` type of the remote service to be something like `PersonName`, however, as I mentioned above, these external schemas should be immutable.

Is there a way to rename a restricted type **before** this exception is thrown at the Gateway level?

Answer (score 0):

Add a call to `RenameType`:

```
public virtual void Add(IRequestExecutorBuilder builder, bool ignoreRootTypes = true)
{
    var type = this.GetType();
    builder.AddRemoteSchema(type.Name, ignoreRootTypes);
    builder.RenameType("Name", "PersonName", type.Name);
}
```

This will rename the incoming type from your remote schema to something else.

Comment: I've tried this, but unfortunately if there is a type collision, the code never reaches the "RenameType" call. For example, I have a property in a schema called "Name", and before I can even rename it at the Gateway, I get an error during stitching that Name has already been added to the dictionary (I assume Name is reserved).